# iOS tracking user position when he is not moving

Tags: ios, gps, location, cllocationmanager

My problem is when I´m tracking the user position when he is not moving.

**The situation is:**

User is walking and he stops. 1 minute later he starts moving again. When starts moving again, the position captured by GPS is "bad" and it gets better as time goes up, 3 or 4 attempts later the position is good. The resulting track when he starts moving again is a weird line of points until he gets a good position. I tried to filter the positions that has a bad accuracy, but i can´t relay on this. bc sometimes, the signal is bad and a bad position for me will be probably the best I can get. Is there some way to detect "calibration points" and keep only the best of them?

[image]

Comment: Hi David, I'm also having same issue, How did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Refer at the `horizontalAccuracy` of the `CLLocation` object. That will give you a good sense of how accurate the location update is. As the docs say:

> The location’s `latitude` and `longitude` identify the center of the circle, and this [`horizontalAccuracy`] value indicates the radius of that circle. A negative value indicates that the location’s latitude and longitude are invalid.

If you want, you might disregard locations whose `horizontalAccuracy` is not sufficiently accurate.